# How do I write this SQL code with output on the same table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I know there's a way to do it in SQL Server, but after hours of troubleshooting, I still haven't yet figured it out.

I want gender and 2 year survival output in the same table. Here's the code I used for the separate outputs by gender:

```
-- Count # of patients by gender and count the number of patients that are alive - Females

SELECT twoYrSurv AS WOMEN_2_YR_SURVIVAL, COUNT('gender') AS GENDER_TOTALS
FROM dataLungCancer1$
WHERE gender = 'Female'
GROUP BY twoYrSurv

-- Count # of patients by gender and count the number of patients that are alive - Males

SELECT twoYrSurv AS MEN_2_YR_SURVIVAL, COUNT('gender') AS GENDER_TOTALS
FROM dataLungCancer1$
WHERE gender = 'Male'
GROUP BY twoYrSurv

-- Results after changing group by clause
SELECT twoYrSurv AS Two_YR_SURVIVAL, COUNT('gender') AS GENDER_TOTALS
FROM dataLungCancer1$
GROUP BY gender, twoYrSurv
```

Output

```
Two_YR_SURVIVAL GENDER_TOTALS
-----------------------------
Alive              86
Alive              201
Deceased           60
Deceased           103
```

Comment: Why not just `group by GROUP BY gender, twoYrSurv`? And remove the where clause.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Dale! I tried group by numerous times and got errors. I just tried it as you listed but I don't get male or female info about the results. I do think this is on the right track though, thanks again!

Comment: I need a column with female and male gender or the rows can have the label, either way I need to see gender labels in the output. Thanks again!

Comment: You just need to add gender to the select list.

Comment: Perfect, I knew I was missing something easy, I putting it in the wrong place (or forgot the comma?) . I'll post the solution in the question for everyone, many thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
SELECT twoYrSurv AS TWO_YR_SURVIVAL, gender AS GENDER, COUNT('gender') AS GENDER_TOTALS
FROM dataLungCancer1$
GROUP BY gender, twoYrSurv
```

Results:

[image: Lung_Cancer_Survival_By_Gender]

Comment: I hope you realize that `count('gender')` and `count(gender)` are very different things. Here you got lucky and it makes no difference.

Comment: Yes syntactically, they are different but it appears that they're read the same. Not luck, just how the programming language works in this case.